# Why do variables get into for loops with zero length?

Tags: r, loops, iterator

can somebody explain why for loops are executed even on variables with zero length? For example

```
listFunction<-function(listinput)
{
for (i in 1:length(listinput))
{listinput[i]<-listinput[i]+1
print("googats")
}

  listinput
}

listB<-c()

listFunction(listB)
[1] "googats"
[1] "googats"

> listB
NULL
```

why does it iterate the loop twice rather than simply not go in at all?

Comment: the loop iterates from one to zero, so twice. This seems to be whats happening `for (i in 1:0){
  print("googats")
}`

Comment: You can use `seq_along(listinput)` instead of `1:length(listinput)`. This way, with a zero length `listinput`, for loop gets passed a zero length vector, and so doesn't get run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [official documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#for), for loop

> The syntax of the for loop is
>
> ```
> for ( name in vector )    
>     statement1
> ```
>
> where vector can be either a
>   vector or a list. For each element in vector the variable name is set
>   to the value of that element and statement1 is evaluated. A side
>   effect is that the variable name still exists after the loop has
>   concluded and it has the value of the last element of vector that the
>   loop was evaluated for.

So, it will iterate through each element.

In your case,

```
for (i in 1:length(listinput))
{
    listinput[i]<-listinput[i]+1
    print("googats")
}
```

is like

```
for (i in 1:0)
{
    listinput[i]<-listinput[i]+1
    print("googats")
}
```

since there are 2 elements `1` and `0` in your vector, the loop body will be iterated twice.